# Remove margins around subplots in Plotly

Tags: layout, plotly, subplot, choropleth

I have a plot made up of 3 choropleth subplots next to each other. I set the overall height and width to my desired dimensions (800 x 400 pixels). I want each subplot to go from top to bottom, but as it stands, the subplots retain the aspect ratio of 2:1, meaning I have wide margins at top and bottom. Those I want to remove.

As a minimum example, I am attaching the data and plot code:

The toy dataset:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon

minidf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dict(
    krs_code = ["08111", "08118"],
    m_rugged = [42.795776, 37.324421],
    bip = [83747, 43122],
    cm3_over_1999 = [47.454688, 47.545940],
    geometry = [Polygon(((9.0397, 48.6873),
                         (9.0397, 48.8557),
                         (9.3152, 48.8557),
                         (9.3152, 48.6873), 
                         (9.0397, 48.6873))),
                Polygon(((8.8757, 48.7536),
                         (8.8757, 49.0643),
                         (9.4167, 49.0643),
                         (9.4167, 48.7536),
                         (8.8757, 48.7536)))]
)).set_index("krs_code")
```

The plotting code:

```py
import json
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows = 1, cols = 3,
                    specs = [[{"type": "choropleth"}, {"type": "choropleth"}, {"type": "choropleth"}]],
                    horizontal_spacing = 0.0025 )

fig.update_layout(height = 400, width = 800,
                  margin = dict(t=0, r=0, b=0, l=0),
                  coloraxis_showscale=False )

for i, column in enumerate(["m_rugged", "cm3_over_1999", "bip"]):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Choropleth(
                 locations = minidf.index,
                 z = minidf[column].astype(float), # Data to be color-coded
                 geojson = json.loads(minidf[["geometry"]].to_json()),
                 showscale = False
                 ),
        col = i+1, row = 1)
    
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)

fig.show()
```

Notice the margins at top and bottom, which retain the aspect ratio of each subplot, while they are supposed to stretch from top to bottom:

[image]

I tried several parameters within go.Choropleth() and .update_layout(), but to no avail.